# How do I retrieve only one data column of the latest date?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have 2 columns of information，*time check in* and *time check out*. I filled in these 2 columns by retrieving data from *attendance_records_table*. Below are the code to retrieve data from the table,

```
@foreach(App\Models\AttendanceRecord::get() as $data)
<td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm text-gray-500"></td>
<td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm text-gray-500">{{$data -> date_checkIn}} <br>
{{$data -> time_checkIn}} <br>
{{$data -> location_checkIn}}
</td>

<td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm text-gray-500"> <br>
{{$data -> time_checkOut}} <br>                                                             
{{$data -> location_checkOut}}
</td>
@endforeach
```

Now the data is showing but it is showing all the info that are in the table. I want it to be showing only the latest date. I attach here 3 screenshots so you can understand my situation better and also how the data in attendance_record table is also used to store a historical data. Please help.
https://paste.pics/b4d3ee73973a07e36a509a1176f88870, https://paste.pics/1d09d18e404e57bcac528f5276f473e6,
https://paste.pics/d17371f74cd21bf598f41e54522d9a08.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the latest record by using the orderBy and first method.

In your controller you can

```
 $data['latest_date'] = App\Models\AttendanceRecord::orderBy('date_checkIn', 'desc')->first();
 return view('your_view', $data);
```

and in your view you can access by $latest_date variable

and avoid writing eloquent queries in the views for cleaner code and good practices.